# Do I need to synchronize a getter function between multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So if I have multiple threads wanting to access a variable in the same object, using a getter, do I need to `synchronize (var) { var.get(); }`?

I'm sure it would be needed if it was a setter, as any other thread could be setting a new value.

But in this case, this variable is only read by the threads and does not change.

Though, multiple threads could be checking its value at the same time.

Do I need to synchronize the getter?

Comment: _"do I need to"_ - to achieve what? Also consider: there _are_ non-atomic reads. But if it is a constant, basically, not even this will be relevant.

Comment: You need to ensure that the write or the initialization of the variable "happens before" all the reads. If it happens before the reading threads have been created, then that is sufficient, but if it happens after the threads have been created then you may need some additional synchronization.

Comment: Generally speaking synchronizing a single getter is often insufficient to get real thread safety. But there's no universal "yes/no" answer to this kind of question, because it really depends on *a lot* of details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in this case, this variable is only read by the threads and does not change.
> Though, multiple threads could be checking its value at the same time.
> Do I need to synchronize the getter?

The devil is in the details here.  Whether you can access the variable in multiple threads depends on whether or not the field is `final` and whether the object was created *before* the threads were by the same thread that started the threads.  That is the only guarantee that the Java memory model gives in terms of publishing classes.

If the field is `final` then it is guaranteed to be appropriately initialized and visible to other threads.  If it is not final, regardless if the threads just read the field, if the object was created after the threads were running, you will need to synchronize on it (or mark it as volatile) to gets its memory updated and to insure that the field has been appropriately initialized.

Answer (score 2):

As you state the variable does not change you do not have to synchronize parallel read access.